# java function - print(collection c)?

Tags: java, function, input, collections

I'm trying to learn java better and I got one question.

Say I got two collections, an ArrayList and a LinkedHashSet. Is it possible to make a function like this:

```
void print(collection c) {
    for (object tmp:c) {
        System.out.println(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just capitalize Collection and Object and then you're done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Watch your capitalization:

```
private void printCollection(Collection collection) {

   for (Object obj : collection) {
      System.out.println(obj);
   }
}
```

Comment: Should be `for(Object obj : c)`

Comment: Seconds too late. Should be `Collection<?>`, and `element` or `e` instead of `obj`.

Comment: Make sure you implement the toString() method

Answer (score 2):

Yes. ArrayList and LinkedHashSet are both Collections. The method that you wrote accepts a Collection (note the capital C) so it will accept any type of collection. This is referred to as polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, as both types implement `Collection<E>`. The convention is for class types in Java to start with a capital letter. Since 1.5, Java has used [generics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) for its collections and you should use them in all new code. Since you're using the 1.5 style `for` loop, you should write generic code.

It's usually better to make functions operate on the least specific type as possible, as this gives the widest reuse. In this case, you only need something wich could go one up from `Collection<T>` to `Iterable<T>`, as you only need something which will work with the for loop. So combining generics and least power gives:

```
public class PrintLinePrinter {
    public <T> void print (Iterable<T> collection) { 
        for (T item : collection) {
            System.out.println(item); 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: The `T` is unnecessary. just do `public void print (Iterable<?> collection)` and change `T item` to `Object item`

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println(Collection c) already print any type of collection in readable format.
But if collection contains user defined objects , then you need to implement  toString() in user defined class.

Answer (score 1):

'**Loop free**' solution:

```
void print(collection c) {
    System.out.println( Arrays.toString(c.toArray())); }
```

Answer (score -2):

basically you just need ot use the iterator:

```
void print(collection c) 
{ 
    for (object tmp:c.iterator()) 
    { 
        System.out.println(tmp); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: In Java, iterators are not iterable. You can only use for-each on iterables, not iterators.

Comment: ack, true.  but who was the genious who decided that? :)